# Javascript onmousemove behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

I have a canvas with a circle drawn on it. I would like a particular animation to appear on the canvas when the pointer is inside the circle. When the pointer is outside the circle I would like the canvas to be back to normal. The animation is created using animate() that runs for like 5 seconds. The code I have used to check if my pointer tracker works properly is :

```
 if (context.isPointInPath(x, y)){ 
     document.getElementById("Show").innerHTML = 'inside';
    }
 else{
     document.getElementById("Show").innerHTML = 'Not inside';
 }
```

This seems to work fine. I get 'inside' printed when the pointer is insdie the circle and 'Not inside' when the pointer is outside the circle. However, when I add the animate() function that runs for 5 seconds :

```
 if (context.isPointInPath(x, y)){ 
     document.getElementById("Show").innerHTML = 'inside';
     xe = 10; // reset xe again
     animate();
    }
 else{
     context.clearRect(70, 0, 1000, 70);
     document.getElementById("Show").innerHTML = 'Not inside';
 }
```

the whole behavior is affected. Initially when the pointer is outside the canvas, I get 'not inside' and no animation. But as soon as the pointer enters the circle, I get 'inside' for like a millisecond, animation starts and the text is changed to 'Not inside' even when the pointer is inside the circle. After the pointer leaves the circle and enters the circle again, the animation does not happen again. It's like once the pointer enters the circle initially, the animation starts once and the whole thing is frozen. Could you guys help me out with this. Thanks.

BTW the animate function:

```
var xe = 10;
var speed = 30;
function animate(){ 
reqAnimFrame = window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame ;
reqAnimFrame(animate);
if (xe >1000){
    return;
}
else{
    xe +=speed;
}
draw();  // draws a circle with center xe
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], otherwise there is simply to much work to reproduce the behavior in order to provide an accurate answer to your problem

Comment: And what does the `draw()` function do? BTW: `window.requestAnimationFrame` has been available unprefixed in all browsers since roughly 2013; you don't need to (and shouldn't) use the prefixed names.

Comment: (Bonus BTW: `msRequestAnimationFrame` and `oRequestAnimationFrame` never existed! MSIE and Opera didn't use a prefix for that feature.)

Comment: If you don't stop your animation loop, then it will continue (making your clearRect useless) And if you never reset `xe`, then once it will have reached `>1000` you won't `draw` anymore.

Comment: Hey I think I'm resetting xe before calling animate()...

Comment: Well it's hard to tell for sure how everything is scoped in your script since we get it all mashed up, but at first glance, there is nothing resetting it no. You do set it once in what seems to be the global scope, then increment it in animate, and that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

See [window.requestAnimationFrame()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

`reqAnimFrame(animate)` in `animate()` caused recursive call, which could be avoided by placing it after `return` condition

```
function animate(){ 
    if (xe >1000){
        return;
    }
    else{
        xe +=speed;
    }
    draw();  // draws a circle with center xe

    reqAnimFrame = window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame ;
    reqAnimFrame(animate);
}
```

Comment: Hey this seems to give the same output :/